# I want to choose an SSD for a laptop

Tags: ssd

I know which SSD suits best my laptop, but I don't know what interface suports, how can I find out?

Comment: Most modern laptops use sata or M.2, sata is z height/2.5 inch . Without more information its impossible to tell what you need. You might also have msata in slightly older boxen

Comment: Attach a link or a picture of the item you are trying to buy to make it easier for us to help.